# Ajax and grails render

Tags: ajax, grails, render

I'm trying to read XML with AJAX, all the data are took from a well formed XML file and then are sended to client page through AJAX. But xmlhttp.responseXML always remains unusable.

Here's my controller :

```
def fileGetter = {
    if (params.fileId) {
        try {
            String resultStr = fileManipulatorService.fileProvider(params.fileId).getText()
            println resultStr
            render(text: resultStr, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1")
            response.sendError(200)
       }
    }
}
```

`resultStr` contains the proper xml, on my webpage xmlhttp response text contains the correct xml data too while xmlhttp response xml contains nothing. How can I send true xml data to my client page and exploit it? I need too work with an XML response. (I tried to send a new xml object created from the string, I tried to return the original file, but none of these methods worked)
(I'm using Chrome)

Thank you

Comment: Do you really mean `response.sendError(200)` ? You may want `response.setStatus(SC_OK)`. Also try to set it before `render`

Comment: why dont you `def xml = XML.parse(fileManipulatorService.fileProvider(params.fileId).getText(), "UTF-8"); render xml as XML`

Comment: sendError doesn't solve it. And for XML.parse, it generates an error No signature of method: static grails.converters.XML.parse(). Just like if didn't import the grails xml converter. I don't understand why. I'm getting more and more lost...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but this code doesn't make any sense

```
render(text: resultStr, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1")
response.sendError(200)
```

Grails does not return after executing `render` so it will execute the `response.sendError` after returning valid data. Replace these lines with

```
render(text: resultStr, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may try 
    render resultStr as XML

It should work, thougt I don't really like these [converters](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference).

Comment: Hello, maybe I'm not using it properly but I just try render resultStr as XML it didn't work and XML.parse(resultStr) as XML didn't work either? any idea why? It generates errors like: runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException or with class cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to class 'grails.converters.XML'

Comment: In fact it's pretty normal. A single string is *valid* xml. Usually converters are for property:value set to <property>value</property>.